# Insert date now + interval 2 days

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax-error

for some reason I am getting a syntax error:

```
dflgudv3jfgeq0=> INSERT INTO habit_instances (habit_id,completed,create_date,due_date)
dflgudv3jfgeq0-> VALUES
dflgudv3jfgeq0-> (1,FALSE,NOW(),NOW()+INTERVAL 2 DAYS);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "2"
LINE 3: (1,FALSE,NOW(),NOW()+INTERVAL 2 DAYS);
```

From what I've read this should be the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interval value needs to be enclosed in single quotes:

```
INSERT INTO habit_instances (habit_id, completed, create_date, due_date)
VALUES (1, false, now(), now() + interval '2 days');
```

The specification `'2 days'` as a single string is a Postgres extension to the SQL standard. A SQL standard compliant way of writing this would be `interval '2' day` or written with a full interval specification: `interval '2' day to minute`

Answer (score 0):

```sql
INSERT INTO habit_instances (habit_id,completed,create_date,due_date)
VALUES (1,FALSE,NOW(),NOW()+INTERVAL '2 day');
```

both forms `2 day` and `2 days` work

Answer (score 0):

In SQL standard run below code.

```
INSERT INTO habit_instances (habit_id,completed,create_date,due_date) 
     VALUES (1, FALSE, GETDATE(), DATEADD(day,+2,GETDATE()));
```